# Where should I configure my DI container for domain infrastructure services in DDD?

Tags: dependency-injection, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I am trying to figure our where the code for configuring my dependency injection container for my domain repository services lives.

My initial thought was to let the client configure all services, but then the client needs to be aware of the repository service, which I don't want to expose in the client.

**I was thinking that each layer could configure its own service dependencies via an exposed configuration method or class?**

Comment: I always create specific layer with all DI configuration on top of application layer.
Thanks to that I don't need to repeat myself for all UI (rest, cli, soap etc.) layers the DI configuration.

It's a bit different if, you use hexagonal architecture, then it should live within infrastructure layer.

Comment: "domain repository *services*" ? ...

Comment: You usually want to configure all of your DI at the application entry point http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/

Comment: @guillaume31 I just meant the repository that I inject into my domain service.

Comment: How does that work when I need to configure dependencies that are not available (hidden by access modifiers) in the composition root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My initial thought was to let the client configure all services, but
>   then the client needs to be aware of the repository service, which I
>   don't want to expose in the client.

What I tend to do is still follow the Composition Root pattern, where my web project would be the first place where the IoC wiring-up would start (i.e. the usual sort of 3rd party library that would hook itself into the controller factory).  But I then configure the rest of my IoC bindings by referencing an IoC module (in my case I usually use Ninject, so I reference a `NinjectModule` from my web project).  But I put this `NinjectModule` in a separate infrastructure project.

I can then reference this IoC infrastructure project from my web project and the IoC project can reference every other project in the solution.

This way I don't have to create project references in my web project to things I might not want my web project to access, like my repository layer.

Answer (score 2):

*The answer has already been given in comments, I'm just wrapping it up in a proper answer here.*

Unless you use a special-purpose architecture like a plug-in architecture, **you should always configure the DI container at a single place, as near to the application entry point as possible. This is called the composition root.**

It doesn't matter if the configured type is a repository, factory, domain service or application service. All DI configuration should go in *one* place.

See [this blog post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) for a good introduction on the details of composition roots.

Comment: How does that work when I need to configure dependencies that are not available (hidden by access modifiers) in the composition root.

Comment: By *not* hiding it from the composition root. Either make it accessible through the access modifiers (preferred), or use a mechanism like InternalsVisibleTo in .NET (I'd recommend against that, but its an option).